# Не могу понять в чем заключается ошибка

Tags: python

[image: задание]

[image: код]

[image: пример]

Не могу понять в чем ошибка. Выдает неверный ответ.

Comment: Постарайтесь вводить код текстом а не картинкой. Так с ним будет удобнее работать.. Скопировать код с картинки через ctrl+c  сложно...

Answer (score 3):

У Вас по заданию стоит "Или", а в программе Вы пишите "и" (and).
Пиши вместо and - or

Comment: <3 thx, спасаешь меня!

Answer (score 0):

```py
c = 0
n = input().split() # получаем сразу все данные строкой 15 91 90 0 и создаем список
for item in n:
    i = int(item) # приводим строку к числу
    if (i%5 == 0 or i%9 ==0) and i != 0:
        c+=1
print(c)
```